# APScheduler on Flask to pick up data and save where it left off

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, apscheduler

Using Flask, SQLAlchemy, I am making a website and have a function that aggregates stock prices. I would like to save data in Postgres, using APScheduler. But I also want it to pick up on where it left off.

Since the server is just on local machine, it is not always running. If I turn it off in the middle of the week on wed and turn it back on on Monday, I would like it to fetch and save data from wed~ now.

From APScheduler doc, I figured as long as the server is always running, this function should run.

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()   

def save_stock_price():
    """save stock prices to psql db"""
    tickers = all_tickers()
    stock_prices = fetch_all(tickers)
    data = StockPrice(data=stock_prices)
    try:
        data.save() # runs db.session.add(self), db.session.commit()
    except (KeyError, RuntimeError):
        pass

def schedule_stock_price(scheduler):
    """1600, weekdays"""
    scheduler.add_job(id='Scheduled task3',
                  func=save_stock_price,
                  trigger='cron',
                  day_of_week='mon-fri',
                  hour='16',
                  minute=1,
                  timezone='EST'
                  )
    try:
        scheduler.start()
    except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
        pass


schedule_stock_price(scheduler)
```

But this is set to run at 16:01, once a day during weekdays.

How can I enable it to pick up from where it left off and fill the gap?

Answer (score 1):

From a design pattern standpoint, you may be approaching this from the wrong angle. A scheduled job is stateless in the sense that it either "should run right this minute", or should not. In order for it to "fill in the gaps" you would have to introduce another process. What about having a second scheduled task whose primary job is to determine if any days are missing data, and go out and fetch it if so? A simplified process might be something like this

- Daily Process (call this Process A) is set to run every day at a specified time. When it executes, it writes a row to a database containing the stock price(s).
- Gap Process (call this Process B) is set to run every day *after* Process A would run, so that if Process A executes on a Monday then Process B will see that Monday has data.
- Process B's job is to

  1. Get the last, most recent database row and check the date stamp
  2. If the date stamp matches the current date, do nothing and exit.
  3. If the dates are different, determine all the dates between the last row and the current date
  4. For each of those missing dates, go and fetch the data
  5. Write this data to the database

Depending on how long Process A would take, you would definitely want Process B to start *after the latest time that Process A would ever be running* in order to avoid a case where they overlap, which could cause some race conditions if your logic is not implemented carefully.

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion. After reading this I am seeing why I had struggled, basically had to look at it from different perspective and break down the problems into smaller pieces.